# Solve a mathematical expression containing a variable

Tags: java, math

How to resolve dynamically a mathematical expression that containing a variable (may appear several times).

Only the basic operators are necessary `(+ - * /)`.

Example expression (`x = 10`):

```
4x * (4 - (8 / 4)) + (5x - (2 * 3))
```

Comment: The value of the variable is given a priori? Shouldn't you write `4 * x` instead of `4x`?

Comment: We aren't going to write the program for you. Try writing it yourself and if you get stuck, ask a specific question about what you're stuck on.

Comment: A hint is to use a stack during evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Shunting Yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is the standard algorithm for parsing mathematical infix expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this many times, but the best way of doing it tends to change with each major version of Java. Get ready, this is a mouthful.

For something like this, I encourage you to look at `java.util.function`. I would go about it by setting up a mapping of each operator (*/+-) to a BiFunction describing how to do it. You will also want a precedence order, so + is not given a higher order-of-operation than *.

Next up, you'll want to construct a regular expression that pulls out inner contents of parentheses, without the parentheses themselves. Construct a tree of operators and their operands, in an effort to convert it to reverse-polish notation; do this one innermost-parentheses-set at a time. Once you have an ordered set of BiFunction operations and can retrieve a numeric value, replace the parentheses with the value, and scan again, until no parentheses are left. Then, just finish the thing off by solving it independently.

Like I said, a mouthful; but you're basically looking at a context-free grammar. If you want further details, and a lot of example code (in Java), I'm actually working on a book on this right now. You'll find a lot of my initial material, sans any final editing, at: https://michaelericoberlin.wordpress.com/category/software-language-engineering/

I wish you luck, I know that it's a much bigger deal than it looks.

Comment: Note that for the tree, you're basically moving toward shunting-yard, but with parentheses in mind. Do yourself a favor and solve it for parenthesis-free expressions first.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a parser for expressions. A [Recursive Descent Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) can be very simple to implement once you have the [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) definition of your expression language:

```
expression  :  '-'? term (( '+' | '-' ) term)*
      term  :  factor (('*' | '/') factor)*
    factor  :  NUMBER | VAR | '(' expression ')'

    NUMBER  :  ('0'..'9')+
       VAR  :  'a'..'z'
```